# Using Background Tick Image for Selected Swatches, Cannot Be Done Over Image

Tags: css

I have a website where there are colour swatches for users to be able to select for clothing items.

All of the swatches have been rectangles with a background colour. When a user selects a swatch, a background tick image overlay is shown.

I have now had to use a background image for a colour swatch that is half one colour and half another.

The problem is that when a user selects this new colour swatch, they cannot see the background tick image to know that it is selected.

What possible solutions could there be to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: include code in your question, even better : recreate your issue in a fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: We would need to see your code to help you. Also using `CSS` you can have colours half and half. One way to do it [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/aYKB9/) And here is using background [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/aYKB9/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here one option using a pseudo element. I will leave it to you to decide how the 'selected' class is applied but it's a simple JQuery function.

You could replace the `content` with any character or, alternatively use a background image for the whole pseudo element.

[**JSFiddle DEmo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aYKB9/11/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="swatch selected"></div>
<div class="swatch"></div>
<div class="swatch selected"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.swatch {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #bada55;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.swatch.selected {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.swatch.selected:after {
    position: absolute;
     content:  "\2713 ";
    font-size:34px;
    color:black;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-17px; /* 50% of height */
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -17px; /* 50% of width */

}
```